# Initialize select box with the retrieved id

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js and I am trying to code an edit page which contains a select box. It has id as the value and name as the display label.

```
       <select class="form-control" ng-model="item.user" 
               ng-options="user.id as user.loginName for user in Users" ng-disabled="true" > 
    <!-- ng-init="item.user=userId" -->
    <option value="">Select User</option>                                             
</select>
```

As I am adding edit page, I retrieve the values from server side and it returns the id for the select box. When I used ng-init to set the value (See the commented ng-init code), it displays only the Select User option. When I manually provide a user id like

```
ng-init="item.user=3"
```

The corresponding user is displayed correctly in the select box. I tried setting the value from controller as,

```
$scope.item.user = result.userid;
alert($scope.item.user);
```

The alert doesn't throw but when I alert result.userid above it, it works fine. What could be the problem?

EDIT 1:

Sample controller(controller.js):

```
function SampleController(Sample, $scope, $http,$compile, $filter, $modal, $timeout, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder,DTInstances) {
$scope.edit = function(id) {
  //Retrieves value for dropdown
     selectbox.userList(function(result) {
        $scope.Users = result.content;
    });
        // alert("EDIT action initiated ID : " + id);
        var params = {
            id : id
        };

        $scope.sampleObj= Sample.view(params, function() {
            $scope.$state.go('sampleEdit', {id:id});
        });
    }
}
```

state (config.js):

```
.state('admin.editSample', {
              url: '/editSample/:id',
              templateUrl: 'sample/editSample.html',
              data: { pageTitle: 'Edit Sample'},
              controller: SampleEditController

          })
```

SampleEditController(controller.js):

```
var sampleEditController = function($stateParams, $scope, $http){
    var params = {};
    params.id = $stateParams.id;
    var url = "sample/edit";
    $http.get(url, {
        params : params
    }).success(function(result) {

        alert("Users: " + $scope.Users); //Here it alerts undefined
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.Users.length && !$scope.item.user;i++){
            if ($scope.Users[i].id === result.id) {
                $scope.item.user = $scope.Users[i];
              }
        }
    })
```

Edit 2:
SampleRepository

```
@Repository
public interface IUserRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{

@Query("select new com.sample.application.model.dto.SampleInfo(c.id,e.fullName,"
            + "c.accountExpired,c.accountLocked,c.rowCreated,c.enabled,c.rowAltered, c.password, c.passwordExpired, c.loginName, c.languageFluency) "
            + " from Employee c left join c.person e order by c.id asc")
    Page<IUserInfo> getList(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Edit 3:
services.js

```
.factory('sample', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            userList : function(result){
                $http.get('sample/list').success(result);
            } }
```

I also tried this inside the controller,

userRoleEditController:

```
$http.get(url, {
        params : params
    }).success(function(res) {
        selectbox.userList(function(result) {
            $scope.User = result.content;
            for(var i = 0; i < $scope.User.length; i++){

                if ($scope.User[i].id === res.empId) {
                    $scope.item.user = $scope.User[i];
                  }
            }
        });
    })
```

With this I am able to get $scope.User. I tried alerting $scope.item.user after $scope.item.user = $scope.User[i]; but it didn't work and i didn't get the value in the drop down box.

Answer (score 0):

ng-init shouldn't be used to initilise as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). Instead to set the selected item set `item.user` in the controller.

To get the user with id as 3 you will need to loop through the users until you find the correct user. Once found set `$scope.item.user` to the user:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Users.length && !$scope.item.user; i++) {
  if ($scope.Users[i].id === 3) {
    $scope.item.user = $scope.Users[i];
  }
}
```

Edit:

In your service return the promise from `$http`:

```
.factory('sample', ['$http', function ($http) {
  return {
    userList : function(){
      return $http.get('sample/list');
    } 
  }
}
```

Then in your controller where this is called you would do something like this to call this service method, handle the promise, set the users and the user on $scope:

```
sample.userlist().then(function (response) {
  $scope.Users = response.data;

  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Users.length && !$scope.item.user; i++) {
    if ($scope.Users[i].id === 3) {
      $scope.item.user = $scope.Users[i];
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here is my problem. The id assigned to user is not in order its in random. For example, the id of the 4th element isn't 4 its 1312. The id generated is serial but records have been deleted inbetween.

Comment: Since I am redirecting the page using $scope.state.go('sample'), I will be using a new function as controller. I am not able to retrieve $scope.Users in the function.  I have updated my code. Please check

Comment: Here are you loading the users from the server?

Comment: I use Spring data JPA to load users from server. I have attached the repository code too.

Comment: You don't need to post the server side code. Where is the angular code that performs the call to get users.

Comment: I am using factory method to retrieve the users. Please see added code.

Comment: I've tried to help you out. There are quite a lot of edits to your question. I'd recommend to first go through the angularness tutorial to practice doing this problem that you are having